# How to add a SimpleButton in a Flash Builder project from SWC?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash-cs3, swc, simplebutton

I exported a SWC from Flash CS3 and the assets works, except the Buttons, they look like another library items.

The code:

```
package {
    // ...
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import res.botoes.Pause;
    // ...

    public class Cena extends Sprite {
        // ...
        private var botao:SimpleButton;
        // ...

        public function Cena() {
            // ...
            botao = new Pause() as SimpleButton;
            addChild(botao);
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're importing the correct Class. Does your button Class inherit from SimpleButton, or is that the name of your button Class?

Comment: Yes, I'm importing the correct class and the button is exported from Flash, so it extends the class flash.display.SimpleButton

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

My new solution: Make a MovieClip for each state of the buttons, then construct the buttons this way:

```
var pause:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton(
        new PauseU().
        new PauseO(),
        new PauseD(),
        new Mascara()
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this;
first create SimpleButton and Pause instance, Then cast Pause to SimpleButton,sure about the syntax, otherwise check your custom classes

```
// ...
         private var _pause:Pause();
         private var botao:SimpleButton;
// ...
         public function Cena() {
            // ...
            _pause = new Pause();
            _botao = new SimpleButton();
            botao = _pause as SimpleButton;
            addChild(botao);
            // ...
         }
// ...
```